# AT+STGR (give response) command

Tags: gsm, modem, at-command, sim-card, sim-toolkit

I am tyring to automate our SIM based airtime loading facilities by using good-ol' AT commands to acccess the Sim Toolkit application in our SIMs, My question is regarding the AT Command STGR command type = 2 (get Inkey). In the final dialogue in the Sim toolkit app, there is a choice between OK or Cancel, How do I tell the SIM that the user pressed the "OK" key.

I have tried to following to no success

```
AT+STGR=2,1,"OK"
AT+STGR=2,1,OK
AT+STGR=2,1,"Y"
AT+STGR=2,1,"y"
AT+STGR=2,1,Y
AT+STGR=2,1,y
```

> The documentation for my moden (sierra gl6110) says that : 
>   For a GET INKEY with format set to "Yes/No", the data shall contain: 
>   the value"y" when the answer is "positive", 
>   the value "n" when the answer is"negative".

If anybody could help out It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: Sorry this was years ago, I believe we abandoned the idea as doing transactions over SIMs was too slow for our needs, we commissioned a direct connection api to one of our local telcos to perform transactions instead of using the SIM

Answer (score 0):

Try 
AT+STGR=1
It is a best way for confirmation.